# unable to import lodash in angular2 project

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have an app written in `ionic2` and I'm using lodash. With a simple `npm install lodash` on the command line and `import * as _ from 'lodash'` and I can access `lodash` via `_` with no issues

I've started a new app in `angular2 cli`, which is what ionic is built on, and I've tried to do the same thing. i've run `npm install lodash` on the command line and `import * as _ from 'lodash'` but once I try to compile the application I get `ERROR in {DIRECTORY_PATH}/src/app/otherlists/otherlists.component.ts (2,20): Cannot find module 'lodash'.` and I can't seem to get it working. I've even copied the `lodash` folder from the `node_modules` and its no different..

What am I missing?

> EDIT,

to demonstrate this further, I've created a brand new app from scratch.
`ng new parser`
this creates a new angular project. Next command is 
`npm install --save lodash` and I import the library into my project with `import * as _ from 'lodash';`
Once I try and run it with `ng serve` I get the following error:

`ERROR in C:/dev/ionic/parser/src/app/mainpage/mainpage.component.ts (2,20): Cannot find module 'lodash'.`

If I run `npm install --save-dev @types/lodash` I get a long list of errors starting with

```
ERROR in C:/dev/ionic/parser/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (8604,32): ',' expected.

ERROR in C:/dev/ionic/parser/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (8607,14): ']' expected.

ERROR in C:/dev/ionic/parser/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (8607,15): ';' expected.

ERROR in C:/dev/ionic/parser/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (8610,26): ',' expected.

ERROR in C:/dev/ionic/parser/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (8610,42): '(' expected.

ERROR in C:/dev/ionic/parser/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (8610,61): ',' expected.

ERROR in C:/dev/ionic/parser/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (8610,66): ')' expected.

ERROR in C:/dev/ionic/parser/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (8612,15): ';' expected.

ERROR in C:/dev/ionic/parser/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (8612,25): Declaration or statement expected.
```

For posterity, here's my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "parser",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.71",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: npm install lodash only install it, think it needs to be in dependancy for the typescript compiler to import it, try `npm install -S lodash`

Comment: Aaready tried that with no difference

Comment: take look @ this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/#/faq) It has question on how to import third part JS with or without typings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install both the package *and* the typings:

`npm install --save lodash` and `npm install --save-dev @types/lodash`

You will then be able to access the types in the normal way using `import * as _ from 'lodash'`

[This github repository](https://github.com/zbagley/AngularLodash) shows an example of use with Angular 4 and Angular CLI 1.3.

Comment: I've tried it and it still gives more errors with the `typings` install. If I remove the `typings`, I should be able to access lodash but I can't. Like I sat, it works on my ionic project, which is esentially the same

Comment: I've even removed and re-installed node modules but no difference

Comment: Update your question with what you've tried and the corresponding error messages

Comment: I've added another example in the question

Comment: You're using a very old version of Angular CLI, and you'll need to add lodash to your .angular-cli.json file under scripts: `"../node_modules/lodash/lodash.js"`. I would highly recommend upgrading you AngularCLI.

Comment: Another note: Chances are you'll have to use an older version of lodash and its typings if you keep `"angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3"` in your project. Official Angular-CLI is only `@angular/cli` and `@angular/compiler-cli`. This other npm item is likely the root of your issues.

Comment: @mcgowan.b Updated answer with a github repo of a working version of an Angular CLI project with lodash.

Comment: Updating my angular CLI npm installation solved this problem